# Register Assembly in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have used a .cs file in my .aspx page as below:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PreSurvey" Assembly="abc" Namespace="FView.CC" %>
```

It binds some controls to my page, now it gets load when first time page loads, but i want to use it after checking some conditions in my .cs file, Because at first no arguments are being passed so it is throwing error like  "Multiple controls found with same id '0'"

i am using the file in my .aspx page as below

```
<div id="div" style="display: none;">
<PreSurvey:PreSurvey 
    ID="customPreSurvey" ForeColor="Black" SurveyId="0"
    IsPreview="false" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assembly registration is fine. Instead of adding the control to the aspx file, you could use an `asp:Panel` instead of the div, then you can load the control on `Page_Init` (using init to load controls instead of page_load gives more predictable results). Like this:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // first check your conditions, then: 
        PreSurvey customPresurvey = new PreSurvey
        {
            ID = "customPreSurvey",
            ForeColor = Color.Black,
            SurveyId = [your survey id],
            IsPreview = false
        };
        div.Controls.Add(item);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```